# C++ Calculate Amount of time between two times

Tags: c++

I have no experience in C++ whatsoever, so i'm a bit confused - i'm taking a high school programming class and we are expected to do this assignment when we barely know any c++ or programming skills in general.

I'm supposed to write a program that reads the start and end times of an event in 24 hr format. I then need to print the number of hours and minutes elapsed.

```
ex 1: 
first time: 0800
second time: 1705
time elapsed: 9 hr and 5 min

ex 2:
first time:0900
second time: 0800
time elapsed: 23 hr 0 min
```

We are supposed to divide them into two different cases (being where the first time is before the second time and vice versa - we are supposed to be treating both cases the same way). Is there a way to do this without if statements? That would be ideal because we haven't learned them yet.

This is all I have so far:

```
int main() : {

    int first_time;
    int second_time;
    int dif_time;

    std::cout << "Enter first time" << endl;

    std::cout << "Enter second time" << endl;

    difference = second_time - first_time;

    double mod_time = difference % 60;

}
```

Comment: Why the arbitrary limitation "without using `if`" - is that specifically said in your assignment? Are you allowed to use a ternary expression instead? (Which is not an `if` but does the same. Look it up.)

Comment: You have a couple of errors in the code you posted. There is an extraneous ` : ` after `main()` and `difference` has not been declared, you don't return a value in a function returning `int`...

Comment: What kind of class expects you to do an assignment without teaching any of the concepts required for the assignment? Do you at least have a textbook?

Comment: All the solutions require using something even more advanced than an `if`. I can't believe that you were taught any of these other methods if you haven't learned `if` yet, since `if` is one of the most basic programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on posting such a well-written question. You clearly put thought into it and show that you already have done some work.

If you are not allowed to use if statements, your other options are:

- the tertiary operator `?:`
- the `abs()` function which returns absolute value
- Calculate two time differences. One assuming that the first time is greater. The other - assuming that the second time is greater. then take the larger of the two results using `std::max()`.

As this is a homework assignment, I will not provide more details write away. If you need more help, you can ask by editing your question.

Comment: another option: `std::max` or `std::min`

Comment: Thank you, Gene. I added this option.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can take the absolute value of the time difference if you really want to avoid `if`s.</strike> Add 24 hours to the difference, then modulo the difference by 24 hours.

Also, if you plan on taking input in that format, `mod 60` will give you the wrong answer, since `100 % 60 == 40`.

Comment: The absolute value of the difference will give the wrong result. If start is `0900` and end is `0800`, the absolute value will say that it's 1 hour, not 23 hours.

Comment: Didn't notice that example did that. Fixed.

Comment: As I understand the question itself, a start of 0900 and end of 0800 cannot possibly be represented here, because the specification indicates that the order in which the times are provided is not relevant - "(being where the first time is before the second time and vice versa - we are supposed to be treating both cases the same way)"

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It appears from your example output, that for the case that the second time is before the first time, you shall treat it as if that second time was in fact the time of the following day.

In that case, think about *always* adding 24 hours to the time difference and then use the modulo operation to limit the time to below 24 hours.

---

---

This was the content of my post before the edit:

You could make use of the fact that boolean expressions result in 0 (false) or 1 (true).  For example:

```
delta = 24 * (time < 0);
time += delta;
```

This is, however, only in rare scenarios the option of choice.  Unless such possibilities have been discussed in your course, you should probably not make use of this concept for your homework.